# wrong output with large test case in union find

Tags: c++, codeblocks, union-find

I wrote a simple union find implementation using quick find method. Here is my code

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class QuickFind
{
    int* id;
    int size;
    public:
    QuickFind(int n)
    {
        id = new int[n];
        size = n;
        for(int i = 0; i < size; i++) id[i] = i;
    }
    bool is_connected(int p, int q)
    {
        return id[p] == id[q];
    }
    void do_union(int p, int q)
    {
        int tempP = p;
        int tempQ = q;

        for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        {
            if(id[i] == tempP) id[i] = tempQ;
        }
    }
};
int main()
{
    QuickFind obj(10000);
    obj.do_union(5,6);
    obj.do_union(6,8);

    cout<<obj.is_connected(5,6)<<endl;

    for(int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)cout<<obj.is_connected(i,i+1)<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I also wrote a *for loop* in `main`. This prints correct answers when I loop it say 50 or 100 times. But it is giving me all 0s when i loop it like 1000 or more times. I'm using codeblocks ide.

Also when i compiled the same code in codechef's online compiler i get correct output. Can anyone tell me about this anomaly?